# Is there a pair of positive width and length values that will return a negative area?

Tags: c++

I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ 2nd Edition, and he asks how could the post-condition for the function below fail after the pre-condition succeeded.

I guess technically, it doesn't have to return a negative area but so long as the post-condition fails while the pre-condition holds.

This is the last "Try This" from Chapter 5 about errors.

Is there such a pair?

```cpp
int area(int length, int width)
// calculate area of rectangle
// pre-conditions: length and width are positive
// post-condtion: returns a positive value that is the area
{
    if (length<=0 || width <=0) error("area() pre-condition");
    int a = length*width;
    if (a<=0) error("area() post-condition");
    return a;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you have 32-bit integers, and length * width in real terms exceeds (2^31 - 1)?

Comment: Oh yes, that works. It returns a negative number, thanks!

Comment: It would be a good idea if you were to do this *on paper* to get an understanding if *why* 2's compliment numbers behave that way.  It's also a good idea to remember that the behavior is *undefined* in that circumstance -- the hardware or compiler designers are free to do different things on overflow.  Most integers are represented as 2's compliment these days, and most n-bit 2's compliment multiplies just return the lower n bits of the larger, correct number.  But you can't count on that continuing to be the case.  For that matter, technically, you can't count on 2's compliment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result of `length * width` is larger than what fits in an `int`, then you get signed integer overflow. Normally one would assume that the result is negative if that happens. However, signed integer overflow is actually undefined behavior (UB), so it's not guaranteed that the result is negative. Or, even if it is, it's not guaranteed that `a <= 0` will actually be `true` so `error()` might not get called because the compiler could assume that `a` can never be negative. The compiler is free to eliminate branches that could only be reached through UB.

This is unfortunately the nature of UB.